# Formatting snmp batch output

Tags: batch-file, snmp

I am running a command (`snmpwalk`) where I want the output to be exported in a fixed format to a file.

```
snmpget -c test 100.115.128.102 1.3.6.1.4.1.25233.100.3.1.0
```

Current output:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.25233.100.3.1.0 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): 135af92add8cb1bac443e8582775dc41
```

I need to output to display as below when I write this to a file:

```
version=135af92add8cb1bac443e8582775dc41
```

Is it possible to extract only the version info using the batch command and display the output as shown?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-Oe` or `-On` command line options to achieve what you need.
So your command will look like this:

```
snmpget -Oe -c test 100.115.128.102 1.3.6.1.4.1.25233.100.3.1.0
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you provide me the actual command which we need to run?

Comment: Check the parameters! `SnmpGet.exe [-q] -r:host [-p:port] [-t:timeout] [-v:version] [-c:community] [-ei:engine_id] [-sn:sec_name] [-ap:auth_proto] [-aw:auth_passwd] [-pp:priv_proto] [-pw:priv_passwd] [-cn:cont_name] [-ce:cont_engine] -o:var_oid`

Comment: I've modified the answer to provide you with exact command example.